# Convergence conditions for series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to determine the conditions for the following series to converge ($a,b$ and $c$ are positive): $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2a^{\frac{1}{n}}-b^{\frac{1}{n}}-c^{\frac{1}{n}}$$ It's clear that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty }a_n=0$ for all possible values of parameters, but the root test yields 1 and any ratio test seems to be of little use here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a^{\frac{1}{n}}=e^{\frac{1}{n}ln(a)}$

$=1+\frac{1}{n}ln(a)+\frac{1}{2n^2}(ln^2(a)+\epsilon_1(n))$

thus

$a_n=\frac{1}{n}ln(\frac{a^2}{bc})+ \frac{1}{2n^2}(2ln^2(a)-ln^2(b)-ln^2(c)+\epsilon_2(n))$

So, the series converges if

$a^2=bc$.